# Exclude time blocks on particular day [Quartz Schedular]

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quart Scheduler. I want to trigger to in such a fashion so as it excludes timing from xx:xx:xx to yy:yy:yy on day specified (monday, friday. sunday). I know how to exclude particular day. but don't know how not to trigger on given time block on given day?

Can anybody know anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make use of Calendar and HolidayCalendar available in Quartz to achieve this. The Cron expression in Cron-Trigger can also be written smartly to achieve this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/Example3.html, it seems that one can create different job set to do the same task. For each job one can attach a schedule.

If you dont want to run a particular task on say sunday between 1pm and 10pm, but want it to run on sunday the remainder of the day, then you can create two jobs [set to do the same task]. For one give the schedule with time restrictions 00:00 to 13:00. And for the second give time restriction of 22:00 to 23:59.

I hope I understood your problem correctly ...

Comment: that would work fine but I wanted to know that is there any single way by which I can assign timing in a trigger?

Comment: Looking at the scheduleJob definition, it accepts a parameter of type Trigger. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Trigger.html ... Trigger is an abstract class... So, maybe if you really need it, you could implement your own custom trigger ...